# Participe présent versus adjectif

Tags: grammaire, participe-présent

Voici une traduction de quelques vers de Pouchkine par Vardan Tchimichkian :

> Le soir, bien qu'elle aille aussi vite,
> Habitués aux soubresauts,
> Sommeillants, nous gagnons le gîte
> Et le temps fouette les chevaux.

L'adjectif "Sommeillants" traduit "дремля", qui est un gérondif présent en russe. Il me semble qu'on aurait tout aussi bien pu, à la place, avoir le participe présent "Sommeillant". Quelle est la différence de sens entre l'adjectif "Sommeillants" et le participe présent "Sommeillant"? De manière général, dans un cas similaire, y a-t-il un moyen de savoir s'il faut employer le participe présent ou un adjectif?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Sommeiller](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sommeillant/1)*** est un verbe intransitif. On peut choisir d'utiliser le participe présent (sommeillant) ou l'adjectif (sommeillants).

Dans le premier cas, le participe indique l'action de sommeiller alors que dans le deuxième cas, l'adjectif indique l'état des personnes.

La différence est assez ténue.

Le gérondif russe aurait aussi pu être traduit par *en sommeillant, nous gagnons le gîte* mais ce *en* aurait je pense alourdi le style.

Ref. [BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/22915/la-grammaire/le-verbe/modes/distinction-entre-le-participe-present-et-ladjectif-participe)